# Intellij IDEA fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh

I encountered a problem that I can't pull my code from my remote repository in Intellij IDEA .

Here is my error log:

When I change my SSH executable to Built-in, it shows:

[image]

And when I change my SSH executable to Native, it shows:

[image]

But it could work on my Git command line and Eclipse

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I changed my first two pictures

Answer (score 1):

Is your SSH-key protected wit ha passphrase? If yes, the you could use Native only along with some SSH-agent, because native SSH executable means that IDEA expects git to establish SSH connection on its own. In this mode, IDE does not handle any prompts, so if you are prompted for a password or SSH-key passphrase, it will fail.

It is not clear why Built-in executable fails though. 
Make sure your keys are located in .ssh/id_rsa and .ssh/ir_rsa.pub, otherwise make sure to have proper .ssh/config file pointing to the files.

Also, Git Bash is not a valid test, because it is a standalone shell with own environment. Does pull work from the Windows Command Prompt?

Comment: Windows Command Prompt could work. But I met another problem. I can pull my code on my another computer's IDEA  and there is only 'known_hosts' a file in .ssh directory

Comment: Then there is no key in use on the another machine, and you are authenticated by login/password.

Comment: I delete the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub file and replace the known_hosts file on this computer . But still not work

Comment: To authenticate using login/password, only Built-in SSH executable can be used. Make sure it is the one selected

Comment: But I get the error message in the first picture when I set SSH executable to Built-in. And it's unreadable .Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Is the error the same in the log? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085

Comment: 2017-11-30 17:31:53,713 [ 609401]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - '64' ????????????????????????е???? 
2017-11-30 17:31:53,720 [ 609408]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - ????????????? 
2017-11-30 17:31:53,790 [ 609478]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
2017-11-30 17:31:53,791 [ 609479]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
2017-11-30 17:31:53,791 [ 609479]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i know this is old post but for anyone who has this problem ... the cause is fail in ssh key algorithm so check your ~/.ssh/config  and try to fix  the correct algorithm it should look  like this:

```
Host 192.168.9.1
    HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-dss
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Host 192.168.10.13
        HostKeyAlgorithms rsa-sha2-256
        KexAlgorithms   diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
```

there is no need to change ssh-executable to native